# How can I update multiple tables at once in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, update, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have several tables with the exact same structure and I need to update a value in all tables.

In order to do so I tried to build the following script:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  i pg_tables%rowtype;
BEGIN
FOR i IN SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname like 'public' and tablename like '%_knex_migrations'
LOOP
    UPDATE i.tablename SET name = replace(name, '.js', '.ts');
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

I could see that `i.tablename` has the correct value (I inserted in a tmp table to check), but the update fails.

```
name: error
length: 223
severity: ERROR
code: 42P01
internalPosition: 8
internalQuery: UPDATE i."tablename" SET name = replace(name, '.js', '.ts')
where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at SQL statement
file: parse_relation.c
line: 965
routine: parserOpenTable
```

Just plugin `i.tablename` on the `UPDATE` statement doesn't work.

Is there a way to make it work? Or an easier way to update all tables at once?

Comment: `execute format('UPDATE %I SET name = replace(name, ''.js'', ''.ts'')', i.tablename);`

Comment: @dezso: The dupe was not right. `UPDATE` <> `ADD COLUMN`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter it _was_ right, as you see, the OP found a solution based on the dupe (dynamic SQL, where any object name is substituted programmatically).

Comment: @dezso: The OP posted a solution, good - with a sneaky bug, though. Your link was certainly useful. But does that make it a *duplicate*? I wouldn't think so.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter wait, what is the bug on the solution I posted?

Comment: @BrunoLM: Did you see my answer?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter oh the schema thing, ok. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually close.. first create some test data..

```
CREATE TABLE foo_knex_migrations ( name )
  AS VALUES ('test.js'),('test2.js'),('bicycles');
CREATE TABLE bar_knex_migrations AS TABLE foo_knex_migrations;
CREATE TABLE baz_knex_migrations AS TABLE foo_knex_migrations;
```

Next, we're going to use `EXECUTE...`[`FORMAT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), with `%I`.

```
DO
$do$
  DECLARE
    i pg_tables%rowtype;
  BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname like 'public' and tablename like '%_knex_migrations'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE FORMAT(
      $$
        UPDATE %I
        SET name = replace(name, '.js', '.ts');
      $$,
      i.tablename
    );
  END LOOP;
  END
$do$;


TABLE baz_knex_migrations ;
   name   
----------
 test.ts
 test2.ts
 bicycles
(3 rows)

test=# TABLE foo_knex_migrations ;
   name   
----------
 test.ts
 test2.ts
 bicycles
(3 rows)
```

As a side note,

1. In general, you should be using `information_schema` which is standardized for simple things like this, and where speed doesn't matter.
2. You should probably be checking to see if the `UPDATE` needs to run by adding a `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, you're rewriting the table for nothing.
3. In SQL, we don't use naming conventions like this. There is no need for that. If `knex_migrations` has multiple tables, consider `CREATE SCHEMA knex_migrations` to store them, rather than searing through the catalog based on a naming convention for all tables.

Answer (score 2):

[You posted a basically working solution as comment.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174439/how-can-i-update-multiple-tables-at-once-in-postgres#comment337775_174439)

A weaknesses remains, though: If you don't schema-qualify the table name in the `UPDATE` and the schema does not happen to be the first in the current search path, the wrong tables might be updated. Consider instead:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   sch text := 'public';  -- your schema here
   tbl text;
BEGIN
   FOR tbl IN
      SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
      WHERE  schemaname = sch
      AND    tablename LIKE '%_knex_migrations'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format($$UPDATE %I.%I SET name = replace(name, '.js', '.ts')$$, sch, tbl); 
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)